# Recent Video or Pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i would like a little div tag on the left side of my website telling the user which recent pages the user has visited so it is easy for the user to go back to content easily, i have searched in google but i have nothing, maybe javascript or jquery would help me, Thank you

Comment: how are you getting the list of videos in the first place

Comment: no i am not getting the list of videos i need something that when the user has visited the video it shows inside that divtag under recent pages / videos.

Comment: as @ibu says, where are you getting this information from? What video's are we referring to?

Comment: oh sorry, am talking about youtube videos, i embedded the videos

Comment: Are you using any Server Side technologies? If so, what are they?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the first connection on the web site create an array in php something like :

```
 <?php 
      $array_track = array('<li href="www.mywebsite.org/accueil_page.php" />');
 ?>
```

and and show it in you div :

```
<div>
    <?php
         print_r($array_track);
    ?>
</div>
```

To increment you array, right before anything else :

```
<?php
     $current_url = "<li href=\""$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']"/>"; //not sure for that to recover the current url.

     $array_track[] = $current_url;
?>
```

And back to print_r the array in your div.

Hope this will help you.

Edit : There might be some error with the " or the ' in the array, I answer without coding in my IDE, so be aware. But the idea is good, so try it, refactor the code if you need to and enjoy the result! ^^

Comment: He never mentioned PHP, also your answer doesn't address the "recently played videos" and doesn't explain how the array is kept around.

Comment: he asked in html/js, but unfortunatly, with only html, you can only do paint! And with js you only do client side manipulation. Also like I said, the idea is good he just have to refactor it for his own use. The principle will work on asp javascript too, but you'll need to work around to make the cookie crumble.

To kept the array just have to send it pages to pages. not that difficult. In javascript it will be really difficult, because it work on the client side, so not very safe. I think php is the best way.

Comment: What if he is using plain html and javascript? ;)

Comment: By the way, great answer that you have provided in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't kept people from downvote me.the problem is that HTML is only for page creation. With javascript he can do it, but the problem will be passing data to one page from another. It's possible, just had to convert the php to js, anyone can do it.

Comment: My solution helped you? Good for you, keep this little trick in your sleeve, can be usefull ;)